# How to get the value of a column if its name is stored in a variable inside the trigger?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

When updating data in database tables, I need to write to a separate table: table name, change date, old column value, new column value.

I wrote a **trigger**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_update_trigger`
AFTER UPDATE ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

DECLARE done int default false;
DECLARE col_name CHAR(255);

DECLARE counter INTEGER(11);

DECLARE column_cursor cursor for SELECT `column_name`
                        FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
                        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='test' 
                        AND `TABLE_NAME`='users';

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

open column_cursor;

myloop: loop

    fetch column_cursor into col_name;

    if done then
        leave myloop;
    end if;

    /*SET @old_val = OLD.{{col_name}}; <------ HERE */
    /*SET @new_val = NEW.{{col_name}};<------ HERE */

    if @old_val <> @new_val then
        /*INSERT INTO `logs` ....*/
    end if;


end loop;

close column_cursor;

END;
```

I need to get the value from `OLD` and `NEW`.

But column name is in the variable `col_name`.

I tried:

```
SET @old_q = CONCAT('OLD.', col_name);
SET @new_q = CONCAT('NEW.', col_name);

PREPARE old_prepare_query FROM @old_q;
PREPARE new_prepare_query FROM @new_q;

EXECUTE old_prepare_query USING @old_val;
EXECUTE new_prepare_query USING @new_val;
```

But I got an error:

```
Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

Comment: Loops in cursors in triggers noOooooooOooooOOo

Comment: Good. What is the best way to accomplish this task? I'm not very good at MySQL.

Comment: Well, we don't know what you want to do exactly, so it's hard to suggest an alternative, you know? Your code doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: I need to keep track of all the changes in all database tables and record old and new column values in the `log` table.